# datepicker not working used jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Tags: javascript, css, spring, jqgrid

Datepicker is working in below jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#datefrom").datepicker({ 
       changeMonth : true, changeYear : true, onSelect : 
            function(selected) { 
            $("#dateto").datepicker("option", 
            "minDate", selected) }
                });

     <div class="user-form.row">
        <div class="form-lable">From Date :</div> 
        <div class="form-comp">
        <input type="text" size="5" id="datefrom"name="datefrom" required="required" /> 
        </div>
```

BUT datepicker is not working in below jsp I have used same code in both files I have included same .js files in both the files

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        alert("hi doc ready"); //added by Shrikant on 14-12-2015 
        $("#issuedDate").datepicker({ changeMonth : true, changeYear : 
        true });
    <div class="user-form.row"> <div class="form-lable"> Issued date 
    :   </div> <div class="form-comp">   <input type="text" size 
    ="5" id="issuedDate" name="issuedDate" required="required" /> 
    </div> </div>
```

Comment: Do you have `<script type="text/javascript">` around your JS code in the second one?

Comment: yes I hav <script type="text/javascript"> in second one as well...I mapping jsp from controller through spring's ModelAndView class i.e. ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("manage-bonds"); jsp page name is 'manage-bonds.jsp'

Comment: I hav used bellow js 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"/>"></script>`